# Is there a way to find out my Windows 7-version without booting?

Tags: windows-7

I have Windows 7 installed on another partition of my computer. Is there a way I can look up which version of Windows (Home, Professional) I have without booting into Windows? I can access all the files of the system, and open them with an editor, if needed.

I have a calculation running on the computer that I don't want to interrupt, but it won't be done for a day or two, but I'd like to know my Windows version before that.

**Clarification**

The calculation is running on OS X, so unfortunately I don't have access to all the nice Windows tools.

Comment: Is the calculation running in the Windows install you want to check, or in a different OS running in a seperate parition?

Comment: @techie007: The calculation is running on a different OS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to

C:\Windows\System32

read the "license.rtf" file

Comment: Does this file reveal whether it is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: OK - It does not seem to, and includes the text: "The software may include more than one version, such as 32-bit and 64-bit".  But as a general rule, a system will be 64-bit if it includes a "Program Files (x86)" folder, and 32-bit if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Open a [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) window (just type powershell.exe into the search-field in your start-menu) and
type in:

```
(gwmi win32_operatingsystem).caption
```

The output will tell you which operating-system you use.

```
(gwmi win32_operatingsystem).ServicePackMajorVersion
```

... will tell you which ServicePack is installed on your system.

Typing the following will show you, which OS architecture you installed (32-bit or 64-bit):

```
(gwmi win32_operatingsystem).OSArchitecture
```

All of this information are also available if you right-click on "Computer" and select properties.
But truly: PowerShell is the coolest way :)

**Update**:
If you're not running the windows itself, you can still get the Version from windows' registry hives.
You can read it as follows:

- load WIN-HDD:\Windows\System32\Config\SYSTEM into anything that can read windows registry hives.
- then goto: Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
- The windows-version is stored in "ProductName"

Comment: I _think_ he's saying the running the calulation in one OS in one parition, and he wants to get the info from a current-not-running Windows install on another partition. I asked for clarification. ;)

Comment: just for the record, I didn't down-vote you. :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Unfortunately I'm not running Windows on the computer. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: @Jonas: english is not my main-language - my fault ;) if you are able to open registry-hives (I'm not familiar with Mac OSX and don't know if such an application exists), you can read it as follows: load WIN-HDD:\Windows\System32\Config\SYSTEM - then goto: Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion - The windows-version is stored in "ProductName"

Comment: @wullxz - that would make a good answer to the question - I'd upvote it :)

Comment: @mwfearnley: added it to my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the computer was bought new, has an OEM sticker on the bottom, and has not been re-installed since, that will tell you the OS and version.